# Cannot mount or recognize usb flash drive ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount, usb-drive, dmesg

I am having trouble mounting my 16GB usb3.0 flash drive both on windows 7 and ubuntu 14.04.

Device doesn't show on fdisk or when I run lsusb.

This is what I get when I run dmesg after pluging it in. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I don't know if it's related, but the first time I tried using it I experienced a crash on ubuntu.

```
[   55.768914] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[   55.795584] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387
[   55.795595] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   55.795601] usb 3-1: Product: Mass Storage
[   55.795605] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Generic
[   55.795609] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: FA8EDD26
[   55.823608] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   55.823756] scsi6 : usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[   55.823807] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[   56.821322] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[   56.821674] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[   56.822304] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 15663104 512-byte logical blocks: (8.01 GB/7.46 GiB)
[   56.823547] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[   56.823551] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[   56.824208] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   56.828139]  sdb:
[   56.830093] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[   57.247388] systemd-hostnamed[2500]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[  356.974918] sdb: detected capacity change from 8019509248 to 0
[  358.897899] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  367.270539] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  367.295406] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
[  367.295417] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  367.295423] usb 3-1: Product: Silicon-Power
[  367.295427] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: UFD 3.0
[  367.295431] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 1401353601000000
[  367.297277] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  367.297632] scsi7 : usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[  368.526818] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     UFD 3.0  Silicon-Power16G 1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  368.527609] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  368.528638] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 30556160 512-byte logical blocks: (15.6 GB/14.5 GiB)
[  368.529634] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  368.529644] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  368.530660] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  368.539830]  sdb: sdb1
[  368.543535] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  399.379753] usb 3-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  404.371128] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: Timeout while waiting for address device command
[  404.575354] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  404.778430] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 3, error -71
[  404.890571] usb 3-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  409.882324] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: Timeout while waiting for address device command
[  410.086603] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  410.289609] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 3, error -71
[  410.401702] usb 3-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  410.402319] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  410.605655] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  410.808785] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 3, error -71
[  410.920897] usb 3-1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  410.921521] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  411.124768] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  411.327929] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 3, error -71
[  411.328474] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  411.328501] sd 7:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[  411.328517] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[  411.328518] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  411.328520] Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  411.328521] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[  411.328522] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 01 40 00 00 08 00
[  411.328527] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 320
[  411.328530] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 40
[  411.328731] sdb: detected capacity change from 15644753920 to 0
[  411.329448] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88019c0be180
[  411.329452] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88019c0be1c0
[  411.439824] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  411.440048] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  411.643676] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  411.847114] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[  411.959016] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[  411.959230] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  412.162785] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  412.366291] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 5, error -71
[  412.478060] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  412.478261] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  412.682029] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  412.885437] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[  412.997353] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[  412.997598] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  413.201089] usb 3-1: Device not responding to set address.
[  413.404490] usb 3-1: device not accepting address 7, error -71
[  413.404561] hub 3-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
[  646.768145] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  646.786437] usb 4-2: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[  646.790960] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
[  646.790972] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  646.790977] usb 4-2: Product: Silicon-Power
[  646.790981] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: UFD 3.0
[  646.790985] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 1401353601000000
[  646.792857] usb-storage 4-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  646.793286] scsi8 : usb-storage 4-2:1.0
[  647.980627] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     UFD 3.0  Silicon-Power16G 1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  647.981319] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  647.982580] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 30556160 512-byte logical blocks: (15.6 GB/14.5 GiB)
[  647.983466] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  647.983479] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  647.984442] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  647.994070]  sdb: sdb1
[  647.997460] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  683.923838] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: Timeout while waiting for address device command
[  689.119486] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: Timeout while waiting for address device command
[  689.323245] usb 4-2: device not accepting address 2, error -62
[  689.844066] sd 8:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[  689.844089] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[  689.844094] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  689.844098] Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  689.844102] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[  689.844105] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 03 40 00 00 08 00
[  689.844122] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 832
[  689.844130] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 104
[  689.844156] sd 8:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[  689.844164] sd 8:0:0:0: killing request
[  689.844207] usb 4-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  689.846504] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff880222872380
[  689.846507] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff8802228723c0
[  902.274572] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[  902.293221] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1043, idProduct=8012
[  902.293232] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  902.293237] usb 3-1: Product: Flash Disk
[  902.293241] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Generic
[  902.294415] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  902.294674] scsi9 : usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[  903.293930] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB Flash Drive  1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[  903.294720] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  903.295065] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] 2048001 512-byte logical blocks: (1.04 GB/1000 MiB)
[  903.295317] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  903.295325] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  903.295568] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  903.295575] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  903.297265] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  903.297271] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  903.302919]  sdb: sdb1
[  903.304247] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  903.304256] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  903.304262] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  903.554797] systemd-hostnamed[3195]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[  924.855781] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 9
[  924.878581] FAT-fs (sdb1): unable to read boot sector to mark fs as dirty
[  933.681129] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  933.699432] usb 4-1: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[  933.704230] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000
[  933.704241] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  933.704247] usb 4-1: Product: Silicon-Power
[  933.704251] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: UFD 3.0
[  933.704255] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 1401353601000000
[  933.706022] usb-storage 4-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  933.706371] scsi10 : usb-storage 4-1:1.0
[  934.893676] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     UFD 3.0  Silicon-Power16G 1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  934.895563] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] 30556160 512-byte logical blocks: (15.6 GB/14.5 GiB)
[  934.895999] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  934.896523] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  934.896544] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  934.897405] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  934.905207]  sdb: sdb1
[  934.908923] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  970.505295] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: Timeout while waiting for address device command
[  975.701085] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: Timeout while waiting for address device command
[  975.904630] usb 4-1: device not accepting address 3, error -62
[  976.425379] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  976.425395] sd 10:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
[  976.425402] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled error code
[  976.425404] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb]  
[  976.425405] Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  976.425406] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: 
[  976.425407] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 03 40 00 00 08 00
[  976.425412] end_request: I/O error, dev sdb, sector 832
[  976.425415] Buffer I/O error on device sdb, logical block 104
[  976.425616] sdb: detected capacity change from 15644753920 to 0
[  976.425866] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88019c0be900
[  976.425868] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88019c0be940
```

Comment: for the error -62, in my case it was a USB printer that I was connecting to a USB port  2.0. it hinted that the usb cable could be bad, but when I connected it to the usb port 3.0 it worked (after I restarted the printer and after the second time I reconnected the cable on both the printer and the desktop)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your USB drive has problems on both Windows *and* Ubuntu and it's connecting/disconnecting/connecting/disconnecting/... all the time, it looks like your USB stick's control circuit has been busted.

To be absolutely sure:

1. try another USB peripheral on the same port (Keyboard/mouse printer/...)
2. Shut down the machine completely, remove all power & batteries, turn it back on for a second, re-insert batteries & power, turn on and try again

if 1 works and 2 fails, throw away the USB key and buy a new one.

Comment: Turned off for a while and it worked... I guess it was a hardware issue

Comment: Answer adapted.  Please accept so another user can profit from your  experience...